# Swift class properties - does this require an initialization?

Tags: initialization, swift

```
class Something {
    ...
}

class AnotherThing {

    let foo: Something

    init(something: Something) {
        foo = something
    }
}

class ReallyGreatClass {

    let aSomething = Something();
    let anotherThing = AnotherThing(something: aSomething);

}
```

`ReallyGreatClass` throws the following compiler error:

> ReallyGreatClass.Type does not have a member named 'aSomething'

In the Initialization chapter of **The Swift Programming Language** under the subheading *Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function* they throw out the concept of initializing a property's default value with a closure; so let's give that a whirl:

```
let anotherThing: AnotherThing = {
    return AnotherThing(something: aSomething)
}()
```

Well, of course, this doesn't work - it isn't suppose to. As stated in the chapter:

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods.

So, the only way I've found to work around this is by including an initializer method:

```
init() {
    anotherThing = AnotherThing(something: aSomething)
}
```

But, it seems strange that I'd need a one-liner init method just to setup the `anotherThing` property. I'm wondering if I've missed something and there is a way to set the property's default value without requiring the initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't missed anything. If you want to use another property in the initialization, you have to use an initialization method.